# Android App not showing Azure Notification Hub notification while in foreground

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have Notification Hub setup correctly with FCM and my Android app. The problem is when my app is in foreground the notification never shows but debugger catches on OnPushNotificationReceived so I know the setup is working. Also when the app is backgrounded or not running the notification pops up. I think it has to do with the code which I got from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm

Here is my code:

```
public void OnPushNotificationReceived(Context context, INotificationMessage message)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.SetContentTitle(message.Title)
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .SetContentText(message.Body)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .SetShowWhen(false)
                    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);

        notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I test it with your code above,it could work succesfully.Could you provide an example that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Its difficult to reproduce without replicating the whole setup. Can you confirm that you're seeing the notification when your app is in the foreground?

Comment: Yes,i could see the notification arrive,and the small icon is displayed onthe status bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue to be because no NotificationChannel existed so I created it in the contrstructor:

```
    public AzureListener()
    {
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID, "General", NotificationImportance.Default);
        var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(Application.Context);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

It worked after I added this.

Comment: Just checking. Are you basically creating a local notifcation when you recieve the Push Notifcation and then relying on that to display a Notification when the app is in the Foreground?