# Display Push Notifications on Xamarin Android when in Foreground

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.android, notifications, android-notifications

My understanding of "data" notifications and "Notification" notifications is that they are controlled by whether or not you are including the "notification" object in your JSON payload (I am sending these notifications via Azure Notification Hub). Ones without the "notification" object could be considered silent.

This is the JSON payload for the notification

```
json = new JObject
{
    ["notification"] = new JObject
    {
        ["title"] = notificationRequest.Title,
        ["body"] = notificationRequest.Text,
    },
    ["priority"] = "normal",
};

// Action is optional when the notification is not Silent
if (notificationRequest.Action != null)
{
    json.Add(
            "data",
            new JObject
            {
                ["action"] = JObject.FromObject(notificationRequest.Action),
            });
}
```

If the app is in the background and the notification is not a silent "data only" one then the Notification goes straight into the System tray. If the app is in the foreground the OS does not send it to the system tray instead it calls the app

What I really want is for a Notification Alert to popup when the app is in the foreground or the background as it does in iOS.

A couple of threads I have read say that I should be sending data only Push Notifications and then in the OnReceived callback creating local notifications. I am using the `Shiny.Notifications` library to create local notifications but again they go straight to the System Tray. I have tried with and without a Channel

In my Shiny PushDelegate.OnReceived

```
var shinyNotificationManager = Shiny.ShinyHost.Resolve<Shiny.Notifications.INotificationManager>();
await shinyNotificationManager.AddChannel(
                            new Shiny.Notifications.Channel()
                            {
                                Importance = Shiny.Notifications.ChannelImportance.High,
                                Description = "Breathe General",
                                Identifier = "9999",
                            });

await shinyNotificationManager.Send(
    new Shiny.Notifications.Notification()
    {
        Channel = "9999",
        Message = notification.Notification.Message,
        Title = notification.Notification.Title,
        Android = new Shiny.Notifications.AndroidOptions() { LaunchActivityFlags = Shiny.Notifications.AndroidActivityFlags.SingleTop },
    });
```

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68705044/android-app-not-showing-azure-notification-hub-notification-while-in-foreground) suggested that I need to create a Channel. Have I misunderstood how Channels should be used

Comment: Without code, all we can do is speculate. Which is probably not gonna solve your issue. I suggest you share your code and then we can see what is missing

Comment: I was keeping the code back so as not to put off non xamarin Android developers :-) Based on my searching this seems like a common Android issue but I'll edit anyway.

Comment: Lately, I have been trying to configure shiny and I have been facing issues with it. Are you sure this is not an issue with Shiny but an issue with notifications?

Comment: I am not sure but I do know that notificatons going straight into the System tray even when the App is in the Foreground is a common issue on Android whether or not you are using Shiny or Xamarin.

Comment: Can you try this and see if it works for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=macos

Comment: That doesn't help. The closest that gets ius suggested to use Local Notifcations to ensure that a notifcation will appear in System Tray when app is in Foreground. I already know that. I want a visible alert to appear not just a tiny icon in the System Tray.

Comment: It's not that NotificationManager is used to show a visible notification : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with that last sentence